# Problem with Google Maps and Cocoapods and XCode

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I am not a cocoapods expert so I'm a little stumped by this.  One of my projects uses Google Maps and Google Places, and I did a "pod update", which led to "Module Not Found" errors for Google Maps.  The build folder looked odd, so I created a new project, used the same podfile (except for target/project settings) and did a pod install.

In the image below, my big/real project is in the background and it is obvious that the GoogleMaps/Base group/folder is missing entirely, when compared to the foreground project.

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong or how to fix this?  I'm currently reviewing how to uninstall/re-install pods.

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know how/why things got wonky, but doing the following steps seems to have cleared out the issue by removing the pods from the project, then re-adding them:

```
 pod deintegrate
 pod install
```